# Entity Framework Mapping from One side

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5, class-library

Suppose that I have the following

```
public class Post
{
 public Int32 PostId{get;set;}
 public String PostText{get;set;}
}

public class Comment
{
 public Int32 CommentId{get;set;}
 public String CommentText{get;set;}
 public Post Post{get;set;}
}
```

What is the correct way to create a fluent configuration for the relationship in Entity Framework 5? I have been trying for the past hour with a similar class structure in a project am working on but am unable to make it work successfully in order to create the database.

Answer (score 0):

Should have something like this:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 PostId { get; set; }
    public String PostText { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 CommentId { get; set; }
    public String CommentText { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but cannot i do it at all without adding an ICollection<Comment>?

Comment: That's the way to map one to many relationships on EF.

Should add also a PostId property to map the foreign key on the comment entity.

You can find more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx

Comment: Thanks, i was able to find out how to do it as i want it:
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
.WithRequiredDependent().Map(x =>x.MapKey("PostId"));